# How can I format a number to 2 decimal? In some case sprintf function could not show correct result

Tags: perl

For example:

my $num     = 9.4950;

print sprintf("%.2f", $num)

Output: 9.49

But it should print 9.50 result

Answer (score 2):

4950/10000 is a periodic number in binary just like 1/3 is periodic in decimal. Specifically, 9.4950 is

```
         ____________________
1.001011 11110101110000101000 × 2^3
```

It would take infinite resources to store this number as a floating point number. Due to limited resources, a slightly smaller number is stored instead.

```
1.001011 11110101110000101000 11110101110000101000 111101 x 2^3
```

In decimal:

```
$ perl -e'printf "%.100g\n", 9.4950'
9.4949999999999992184029906638897955417633056640625
```

Since the third decimal digits is less than 5, `%.2f` correctly rounds this down to 9.49.

Comment: Is any other function in Perl to round with 2 decimal?

Comment: Sure. There are math modules and stuff. But unless they're buggy, they're all going to give 9.49 as long as you keep giving 9.494999999999999. Because that's the correct answer for 9.494999999999999. If you don't want 9.49, you need to stop trying to round 9.494999999999999.